# Pulse Width Modulation (PWM) with Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, width, pulse, pwm, modulation

I am able to control the output on some pins on a board using a function with Boolean parameters. Would it be possible to use Vb.Net to send PWM signals out?

Comment: You just say "a board".  Can you be more specific about that?  What kind of board is it (Arduino, for example)?  A lot of microcontroller boards have on-board support for PWM signals coming out of specific pins, you just need to program them to send the signal, and to accept some sort of input to change the modulation.

Comment: My board is a Raspberry PI. Am currently using http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=88063#p88063 to control the GPIO